# Create a gzip file like object for unit testing

Tags: python, pytest

I want to test a Python function that reads a gzip file and extracts something from the file (using pytest).

```
import gzip

def my_function(file_path):
    output = []

    with gzip.open(file_path, 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            output.append('something from line')

    return output
```

Can I create a gzip file like object that I can pass to `my_function`? The object should have defined content and should work with `gzip.open()`

I know that I can create a temporary gzip file in a fixture but this depends on the filesystem and other properties of the environment. Creating a file-like object from code would be more portable.

Comment: If you just want to avoid writing to the filesystem, but use the normal fs functions to create the zip file, you could also use [pyfakefs](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs) (the `fs` fixture with pytest). -- Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to that project.

Comment: Also a great idea. Looks like you can mock/fix/fake on every level of the process: The file, the filesystem or the complete open/read process.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Is it possible to use pyfakefs with gzip? I'm having some trouble there.

Comment: @mclzc - if you have problems with gzip and pyfakefs, best create an issue for pyfakefs with more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) and [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) libraries to create in-memory file objects. Example:

```
import io, gzip

def inmem():
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    with gzip.open(stream, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(b'spam\neggs\n')
    stream.seek(0)
    return stream
```

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly was I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You should never try to test outside code in a unit test. Only test the code you wrote. If you're testing `gzip`, then `gzip` is doing something wrong (they should be writing their own unit tests). Instead, do something like this:

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.Mock('gzip', return_value=b'<whatever you expect to be returned from gzip>')
def test_my_function(mock_gzip):
    file_path = 'testpath'
    output = my_function(file_path=file_path)
    mock_gzip.open.assert_called_with(file_path)
    assert output == b'<whatever you expect to be returned from your method>'
```

That's your whole unit test. All you want to know is that `gzip.open()` was called (and you assume it works or else `gzip` is failing and that's their problem) and that you got back what you expected from the method being tested. You specify what `gzip` returns based on what you expect it to return, but you don't actually call the function in your test.

Comment: Good point, makes sense to take gzip out of the equation. I haven't looked into mocking too much but I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit verbose but I'd do something like this (I have assumed that you saved my_function to a file called patch_one.py):

```
import patch_one  # this is the file with my_function in it
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest import TestCase


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_my_function(self):
        # because you used "with open(...) as f", we need a mock context
        class MyContext:
            def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return [1, 2]  # note the two items

            def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return None

        # in case we want to know the arguments to open()
        open_args = None

        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            def my_open(*args, **kwargs):
                nonlocal open_args
                open_args = args
                return MyContext()

            return my_open

        # patch the gzip.open in our file under test
        with patch('patch_one.gzip.open', new_callable=f):  

            # finally, we can call the function we want to test
            ret_val = patch_one.my_function('not a real file path')

            # note the two items, corresponding to the list in __enter__()
            self.assertListEqual(['something from line', 'something from line'], ret_val)

            # check the arguments, just for fun
            self.assertEqual('rt', open_args[1])
```

If you want to try anything more complicated, I would recommend reading the unittest mock docs because how you import the "patch_one" file matters as does the string you pass to patch().

There will definitely be a way to do this with Mock or MagicMock but I find them a bit hard to debug so I went the long way round.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, in my limited use case it is sufficient to go for the solution above. But good to know that I can patch the whole thing ;)